# socket.io basic questions

Tags: socket.io

I have this code in app.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
static = require('node-static');
var fileServer = new static.Server('./');
app.listen(8080);
function handler (request, response) {
    request.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serve(request, response);
    });
}
io.set('log level', 1);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
     socket.on('click', function () {
            socket.broadcast.emit('moving');
        });

});
```

Index.html

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.hostname;
    var socket = io.connect(url);
     socket.on('moving', function () {
        $("body").append('<div class="text">tex</div>');
     });
</script>
```

I want to write simple text(div), but it is not working..where can be problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io won't help observe the `click` event by default.
edit your client-side code as below:

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.hostname;
    var socket = io.connect(url);
    socket.on('moving', function () {
        $("body").append('<div class="text">tex</div>');
    });
    // manually emit the event, or bind `click` inside dom
    // and call socket.emit('click') inside onClick()
    socket.emit('click');
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, emit is the way that a client talks to the server, or a server talks to client(s).  On is how a server receives a client emit, or how client(s) receive a server emit.  So, normally you would have some event on the client, like a button press for example, that would emit to the server that it happened, and inside the servers on, it would take action, possibly emitting to other clients that it has happened.